# Does `sed` exist in all *nixes?

Tags: sed, portability

My application will be running  on all versions of  Unix-based OS, say, Linux, MacOS, HP-UX, Sun Solaris , OSX, etc.

I'm using the following `sed` command in a common place to delete the string matched in a text file:

```
sed -i '/string1/d' mytextfile
```

Will this work in all *nixes?

Comment: As long as the program source is available, and is not platform dependent, then of course!

Comment: Nit: MacOS is a superset of OSX, and not all versions of MacOS are Unix-based. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS

Comment: On OS X, the `-i` option requires an argument, so you'd have to use `-i''` to edit in place.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, `sed` is on all Unix versions. It is [part of the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html): every "official" Unix includes it, and all Linux and BSD distributions include it as well.

There are several different versions of the `sed` command, with different extensions. If you stick to the common subset of `sed` options and language [described by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) then your command will work on all systems.

Comment: Thanks Michael. i couldnt find sed "-i"  option in the POSIX standard page, does it means -i there's a possibility that " -i " option might not be available on all versions

Comment: That's correct. `sed -i` is not supported by Solaris `sed`, for example.

Comment: YES Michael, sed -i , it says illegal option in solaris

Comment: how do i simualte -i option wih -e or any other options in solaris,

Comment: i tried with sed -e '/string/d' file, it deletes, but not updated in the text file, appreciate any help  Thanks

Comment: Copy the file first, then overwrite the old one (or vice versa).

Answer (score 7):

POSIX does not mandate `sed -i` because it is redundant, and also not in line with  the original purpose of `sed`. `sed` was originally meant to edit *streams* (hence its name `s`tream `ed`itor), not files. The correct tool in POSIX to edit files non-interactively is `ed`

```
printf "/text/d\nw" | ed file.txt
```

Sadly, many current systems think `ed` is obsolete and don't provide it by default, even though it is mandated by POSIX... But at least it should be easily installable on most systems (unlike GNU sed, which might requre compilation from the source code).

*EDIT:* Also, contrary to what the wording of the question implies, the `d` command of `(s)ed` does more than deleting the given string, it deletes any line which contains it.

Comment: thanks fkraiem, but no this isn't working fine in linux now, but this is available in POSIX,OK, how safe is below cmd,             sed '/string/d' txtfile > tmpfile && mv tmpfile txtfile

Comment: The only reason it couldn't be working is if your system is one of those I alluded to, in which case `ed` should be in the official repositories. As for the `sed` + `mv` option, it's probably safe, but like the proverbial alcohol-free beer, "it tastes the same, but you know it ain't right".

Comment: what abt this, this falls under POSIX satndard, right,

perl -i -l -p -e 's/pattern/<NULL>/s;' textfile

the above will do what i'm looking for via sed , i.e. del entire line if pattern matches , via cmd line infile

Comment: @user2172617 `perl` isn't POSIX at all; if it is present it will probably be consistent for a simple oneliner, but that one won't do what your `sed` did. With `-p` but **not** `-l` you can use `-e '$_="" if /pattern/'` but I think it's clear to use `-n -e 'print unless /pattern/'`